# Akka java - Synchronized Children Actor

Tags: java, akka

I just started with Akka (in Java) and I have a problem that I do not know how to solve.

I have N players and one oracle.
Once created, all players must communicate with the oracle who must respond "winner / loser".

The problem is that I do not know the strategy to communicate the players in turn, tidily, one at a time: 
 
for example: player1 -> player2 -> player3 -> player1 -> player 2 -> ...

Players class:

```
public class MyPlayers extends UntypedActor {

/*
* I created one context of N Player
*/
public MyPlayers() { }

public void preStart() {
    //in this way all N players at the beginning, start to communicate concurrently.
    ActorSelection oracle = getContext().actorSelection("//Main/user/app/oracle"); 
    oracle.tell(new MyMessage(myValue), getSelf());
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {

    if (msg instanceof MyMessage) {
        //do something
        sender().tell(MyMessage, getSelf());

    }


    if (msg instanceof DoneMsg) {
        if (((DoneMsg) msg).isDone()) {
            log("Stop Players");
            getContext().stop(getSelf());
        }
    }

}
```

Oracle class:

```
public class Oracle extends UntypedActor {
private int nPlayers;
public Oracle(int nPlayers) {
    this.nPlayers = nPlayers;
}

public void preStart() {
    stateGame = false;  //When the play starter, there is not any wins.
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {

    if (msg instanceof MyMessage) {
        if (!stateGame) {
            //do something
            sender().tell(MyMessage, getSelf());
        }
        else {
            //do something
            getContext().stop(getSelf());
        }
    }
}
```

what is the best strategy to communicate the players in an orderly manner by excluding competition?

Thanks to all.

Comment: This is not a clear question, do you want all actors to recieve the message at the same time? Or you just want to know the best way to loop through them and send a message? If it is the latter I would consider removing this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic two options to send messages to actors in an orderly manner: 
1. Round robin router where players are routies
2. Array or collection holding references to players and iterating through them

Unrelated notes:
Avoid actor selection. Pass the oracle reference to the players by their constructor/props or a message. Selection is very rarely justified (mostly just for remoting) and it's a dangerous practice.